# Is it possible to declare template of template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have objects of type 'value' from OCaml in C++ (they are provided by some integration channel, but it is offtopic). This object contains OCaml data of some type (primitive: int, long... or structural). It can be converted to a C++ object, from OCaml int to C++ int, etc by some provided by "caml/mlvalues.h" functions like Int_val (Long_val, Bool_val ...).

I wrapped functions from "caml/mlvalues.h" by some template function `T to<T>(value x)` in `Caml::Value` namespace to improve readability. (Caml::Value::to<bool> better then Bool_val).

**caml.h:**

```cpp
namespace Caml::Value {
  template<typename T> struct CannotConvertTo { };
  template<typename T> T to(value x);
```

**caml.cpp:**

```cpp
namespace Caml::Value {
  template<typename T> T to(value x) {
    if (is_enum<T>::value) {
      return static_cast<T>(to<int>(x));
    }

    throw CannotConvertTo<T>();
  }
  
  template<> int to<int>(value x) {
    return Int_val(x);
  }

  template<> bool to<bool>(value x) {
    return Bool_val(x);
  }
}
```

Also 'value' can contain some structure and we can read fields of this structure by the function Field(value, index). And I trying to implement some generic implementation to convert the 'value' to tuple.

```cpp
  template<> tuple<T1, T2> to<tuple<T1, T2>>(value x) {
    return make_tuple<T1, T2>(
      to<T1>(Field(x, 0)),
      to<T2>(Field(x, 1))
    );
  }
```

Of course, it is an uncompilable code because of unknown types T1 and T2. How to implement `to<tuple<T1, T2>>()`? Is it possible to declare something like a template of a template? Like:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
template<> tuple<T1, T2> to<tuple<T1, T2>>(value x) {
...
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for partial specialization for function template?

Comment: @user7860670 But there's no such thing.

Comment: @user7860670 yes, I can do it for tuple<int, char> and tuple<bool, bool>, but I don't know how to implement partial specialization for tuple with two type arguments in general. (I am not experienced in C++ but I for me this ability looks natural because it avoids code duplication and templates are existing to this)

Comment: @cigien I found something similar but for classes: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzarg/template_template_arguments.htm . Is it impossible to do the same for function?

Comment: Yes, you can only do full specializations of function templates. Maybe you could write a class template, that has an `operator()`?

Comment: You can specialize for `tuple<T1, T2>` just fine using techniques described in one of the questions regarding partial specialization for function template.

Comment: You can indirectly specialize a function by calling a specialization of a class from that function. `template <class T> class Converter { static T To(value x); };` and then `template <class T> T to(value x) { return Converter<T>::To(x);`. Then specialize `Converter` as required.

Comment: Did you consider using or improving [SWIG](https://swig.org/), or *generating* C++ code from an Ocaml program? (maybe your ocaml PPX metaprogram)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No, I integrate OCaml with C++ first time and want to do it at a low level. Maybe next time I will use SWIG

Comment: Then you probably should still think in terms of the interface between Ocaml and C (and be aware of the memory layout done by your C++ compiler, in particular related to vtables)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch As I know there is only one point why we can't integrate OCaml with C++ directly without using `extern "C"` block - linking from OCaml side needs C function names. So, it is enough to declare a function in `extern "C"`. Inside the function, we can use C++ as usual. All rules to live in harmony with OCaml GC are the same for C and C++. I don't know other points. Do I miss something about memory layout related to vtables in the context of OCaml C++ integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward the operation from a function template to a class template and specialise the latter, leaving the former fully generic.

```
// base case: conversion disallowed
template <typename K>
struct convert_to
  { static K convert_to(value) = delete; };

// convert to specific types                                
template <> struct convert_to<int> 
  { static int convert(value); };
template <> struct convert_to<bool> 
  { static bool convert(value); };
template <typename L, typename R> struct convert_to<std::pair<L, R>> 
  { static std::pair<L, R> convert(value); };

// function template, never specialised
template <typename K> K to(value x) 
  { return convert_to<K>::convert(x); }
```

Comment: I think the base case misses `template<typename K>` on top. Is disallowing of the base case necessary to implement this pattern? (I need some logic in a base case)

Comment: Yes it is missing `template<..>, sloppy editing. Will add. You need to have base case, whether it is disallowed or somehow treated generically is up to you.